# Freemarker: null value displayed

Tags: freemarker

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="zipCode" maxlength="5" value="${zipCode!}">
```

When `zipCode = null` (I use Java), the input field displayes `null`. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `zipCode` being assigned? The only way this could happen is, that `zipCode` is assigned using some EL expression, where `null` value is converted to `"null"` string. Or perhaps you've found a bug in Freemarker (which version you use?). :-)

Comment: `zipCode` is a parameter passed in my URL. I use the version 2.3.16.

Comment: I suspect a Java `String` `"null"` was assigned to `zipCode` instead of a real `null`. I don't think 2.3.16 had any such bug. (Still, I would strongly advise against using archeological findings like 2.3.16.)

Comment: @dardy How is `null` passed in the URL? Is it something like `http://.../path?param1=val1&zipCode=&param3=val3&...`, or `http://.../path?param1=val1&zipCode=null&param3=val3&...`? Because in the second URL, you are not passing `null` (empty value) to the  `zipCode` parameter, but a string value `"null"`.

Comment: No it's just that the param `zipCode` is not passed at all. So its value is 'a real `null`' in java.

Comment: I guess under the hood somewhere the null-Url-Parameter was passed to Freemarker with something like String.valueOf(null) which leads to a String containing the word "null".

Answer (score 1):

@ddekany: you were rignt. zipCode has a String value that equals `"null"`.